# Duplicated data entries in PHP array

Tags: php, mysql, database, arrays

I'm not sure if this appropriate on here since it is more of a understanding issue on my part but I''m curious to know why I receive this output:

```
Response id: 3 Question id: 1 Question: What is my middle name? Title: How Well Do You Know Michael
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 3 [r_id] => 3 [1] => 1 [question_id] => 1 [2] => What is my middle name? [question] => What is my middle name? [3] => How Well Do You Know Michael [title] => How Well Do You Know Michael ) )
```

when I run this PHP script:

```
// Grab the response data from the database to generate the form
    $query = "SELECT qr.response_id AS r_id, qr.question_id, q.question, quiz.title " . 
         "FROM quiz_response AS qr " . 
         "INNER JOIN question AS q USING (question_id) " . 
         "INNER JOIN quiz USING (quiz_id) " .
         "WHERE qr.user_id = '" . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "'";
    $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die("MySQL error: " . mysqli_error($dbc) . "<hr>\nQuery: $query");
    $questions = array(); 
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
        echo 'Response id: ' . $row['r_id'] . 'Question id: ' . $row['question_id'] . ' Question: ' . $row['question'] . ' Title: ' . $row['title'] . '<br />';
        array_push($questions, $row);
    }
    print_r($questions);
```

It seems as though there are two entries for each piece of data.  For example, there are two entries of the 'Response id' under index [0] and [r_id].  Both equal 3.  **Is it a delirious fear of mine worrying about duplicated data in my array?**  I'm thinking of the future when I'm doing 10's of queries at a time and whether this will affect speed or accuracy.  Any input is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you check out the documentation of [`mysqli_fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) you see the second parameter `$result_type` which is by default set to `MYSQL_BOTH`.

That means both the numerical field index (`MYSQL_NUM`) and the field name (`MYSQL_ASSOC`) are used as array-index. So if you only need the field name indices you have to use it like that:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    // ....
```

Answer (score 4):

This behaviour is excpected.

From http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

mysqli_fetch_array() is an extended version of the mysqli_fetch_row() function. In addition to storing the data in the numeric indices of the result array, the mysqli_fetch_array() function can also store the data in associative indices, using the field names of the result set as keys.

Answer (score 2):

Reading http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php, it states that the returned value of `mysqli_fetch_array()` (which works the same way as `mysql_fetch_array()`) contains both numerically indexed row data *as well as* field name indexed row data. If you just want field name indexed data, use `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`.

Answer (score 2):

Taken straight out of documentation:

> Returns an array of strings that corresponds to the fetched row, or FALSE if there are no more rows. The type of returned array depends on how result_type is defined. By using MYSQL_BOTH (default), you'll get an array with both associative and number indices. Using MYSQL_ASSOC, you only get associative indices (as mysql_fetch_assoc() works), using MYSQL_NUM, you only get number indices (as mysql_fetch_row() works).

So changing this:

```
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
```

To:

```
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
```

This will return only string keys or alternatively, you could use `mysqli_fetch_assoc`